# Import checked checkbox captions into a table

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a userform from which I want to import values into a predefined table (called "Overzicht").

I have 12 checkboxes (one for each month) and I want one row for each month if that checkbox is checked. I want to put the Caption of the checkbox in one of the columns in the table.

For example, if I check January, February and March, I want to import all values into a table into three rows where the first row the 'Month' columns says "January", the second one "February" etc.

I have code that checks the number of checked checkboxes and creates the same number of rows. I don´t know how to get correct captions in the rows. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kostenoverzicht").Range("Overzicht")
Dim answer As Integer
'check number of rows to insert based on # of checked months
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim rows As Long
For Each ctl In Kostenoverzicht.Frame2.Controls
If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
If Kostenoverzicht.Frame2.Controls(ctl.Name).Value = True Then
rows = rows + 1
End If
End If
Next

answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Zet in overzicht?")

If answer = vbYes Then
rng.Select
Set newrow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(alwaysinsert:=True)
With ws
For rows = 1 To rows
newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 2).Value = Me.CategorieBox.Value
newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 3).Value = Me.SubCategorieBox.Value
newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 4).Value = Me.BankrekeningBox.Value
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 5).Value = "Af" Else newrow.Range.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Bij"
newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 6).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 7).Value = Me.CheckBox1.Caption
If OptionButton3.Value = True Then newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 8).Value = "Ja" Else newrow.Range.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Nee"
Next
End With

End If
End Sub
```

It will give the value "January" to all rows.

I need code to replace the `newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 7).Value = Me.CheckBox1.Caption` to take the caption of the checked checkbox.

I´ve tried to find my answer on several sites.

Comment: So you need to store the name of the checkbox? Why not have a separate sub and pass the name of the checkbox if it is true?

Comment: well, I need to store the captions of the checkboxes and thought I´d do it all at once but not sure how to do that in a neat and quick way

Comment: Try to replace this: `For rows = 1 To rows` with anything else like `For rw = 1 To rows` and obviously the subsequent `...Cells(rows,...` references

Comment: Well, that change gives what I need, except for the column where I want to store the month into, that still gives "January" in all lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind my first answer, I misunderstood and thought it would always go from jan to some other month. But now It seems it could also be just be sept and nov for example. Find old/wrong answer at the bottom. 
Your code is increadibly hard for me to understand for some reason. You check how many rows to insert at the top, then all the rows seem to get the same information put into it since cells 1-6 are values from other non variable/dynamic sources? Im unsure if I understand whats happening.What even is ws? It also kind of calls a userform right? I can"t really rebuilt what you have cuz I don`t quite know.

Best shot:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kostenoverzicht").Range("Overzicht")
Dim answer As Integer
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim rows As Long

answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Zet in overzicht?")
If Not answer = vbYes Then Exit Sub

For Each ctl In Kostenoverzicht.Frame2.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        If Kostenoverzicht.Frame2.Controls(ctl.Name).Value = True Then
            Set newrow = rng.ListObject.ListRows.Add(alwaysinsert:=True)

            newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
            newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 2).Value = Me.CategorieBox.Value
            newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 3).Value = Me.SubCategorieBox.Value
            newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 4).Value = Me.BankrekeningBox.Value

            If OptionButton1.Value = True Then newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 5).Value = "Af" Else newrow.Range.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Bij"

            newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 6).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
            newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 7).Value = ctl.Name 'Or maybe ctl.Caption ?

            If OptionButton3.Value = True Then newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 8).Value = "Ja" Else newrow.Range.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Nee"


        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I hope you see what I'm trying to do here and can fix it to your needs /bug fix it. Like I said, I didnt rebuilt a sheet to test it. Maybe it helps you regardless.

Old:

`newrow.Range.Cells(rows, 7).Value = Format(3 + 31 * (rows - 1), "MMMM")`

Comment: Thanks, this works. I am just a beginning vba user and I was using some code I had on another userform I created a while ago, think the ws comes from there. Now that I look at your code it all looks a lot more logic, I think I got lost in coding a bit (and I need to get more structured in building code ;))
Thanks again, much appreciated

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has helped you, and consider upvoting Ricardo's answer too if it helps.

Comment: Hey, I'm glad it helped you! :) and thx for accepting the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

This code should go behind your UserForm

Here are some suggestions for when you're coding:

1. Use [option explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) so you don't have unexpected behavior with undefined variables
2. Always indent your code (see [www.rubberduckvba.com](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) a free tool that help you with that)
3. Try to separate your logic defining variables and the reusing them

Review and customize the code so it fits your needs.

You can see what's happening in the code by adding a `stop` and pressing `F8` and executing it line by line.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ProcessForm

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessForm()

    Dim targetControl As MSForms.control

    Dim continue As Boolean

    continue = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Zet in overzicht?") = vbYes

    ' If it's not yes
    If Not continue Then Exit Sub

    For Each targetControl In Me.Controls

        If TypeOf targetControl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            Select Case targetControl.Value
            Case True
                ' Call the RecordData procedure (remember to add the controls in the parameters)
                RecordData targetControl.Caption, Me.TextBox1.Value, Me.TextBox2.Value
            Case False
                ' Do something?
            End Select
        End If

    Next targetControl
End Sub

Private Sub RecordData(ByVal recordMonth As String, ByVal textbox01Value As String, ByVal textbox02Value As String)

    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow

    ' Refer to the table (no need for the worksheet reference)
    Set targetTable = Range("Overzicht").ListObject

    ' Add a new row an set a reference
    Set newRow = targetTable.ListRows.Add

    ' Refer to the columns by their header (replace with yours)
    newRow.Range.Cells(1, targetTable.ListColumns("Month").Index).Value = recordMonth
    newRow.Range.Cells(1, targetTable.ListColumns("Textbox1").Index).Value = textbox01Value
    newRow.Range.Cells(1, targetTable.ListColumns("Textbox2").Index).Value = textbox02Value

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works or you need more help

Comment: Hey Ricardo, thanks a lot. This basically does what I want, except that I also have 2 sets of Optionbuttons of which the value now also appears in the 'Month' column. Not sure why, but somehow that´s seen as checkbox as well? But I have a working solution now, appreciate the help!

Comment: yes, did that. Only got the message that my upvote is not visible for everyone (yet). Still a newbee here ;)